# MBED OS 5.9 LoRA set up in SF7

Tags: mbed, lora, lorawan

Do you know how to set up the Spreading Factor to 12 in a Mbed-OS LoRaWAN protocol APIs to connect to a LoRaWAN network using OTAA?

I'm trying to make LoRA node to use Spreading Factor SF12, because the default one is SF7. I know that in the PHY layer we can change Radio configurations. There are several examples to change between the different sub-GHz frequency bands, however, I can't find one on how to change the LoRa modulation SF between 7 and 12 and with a bandwidth of 125 kHz.
I'm using an SX1276 radio at `EU 868 MHz` config.

In the [source code](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.10/mbed-os-api-doxy/lorawan__types_8h_source.html) you can find the SF7-12 different configurations, but there is not a clear way to set it up. These configs are the definitions (#define) DR_0, DR_, etc ).

In the configuration file in the Phy part you find some example like this:

```
        "phy": {
        "help": "LoRa PHY region. 0 = EU868 (default), 1 = AS923,
         2 = AU915, 3 = CN470, 4 = CN779, 5 = EU433, 
         6 = IN865, 7 = KR920, 8 = US915, 9 = US915_HYBRID",
        "value": "0"
    },
```

But there is no examples or description for the Spreading Factor.

I would like to change it via source code, rather than the configuration file.

EDIT 1:

after Jon's answer, I add the following lines, but still not forcing the SF12 Joins.

```
retcode = lorawan.disable_adaptive_datarate ();
retcode = lorawan.set_datarate (0); //  DR_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call:

```
lorawan.set_datarate(0); // SF12 125 KHz
```

Make sure to:

1. Disable ADR.
2. Either use ABP, *or* call the function above in the `JOIN_SUCCESS` event handler. This is because join procedure always starts at SF7, and then keeps the data rate on which the join succeeded.

Comment: I added    ' retcode = lorawan.disable_adaptive_datarate ();  retcode = lorawan.set_datarate (0);  ' and it is not forcing the SF12 JOINS.

Comment: Joining always starts at SF7 as per the LoRaWAN specification. You can either force data rate after joining or use ABP.