# How to set a specific LoRa Spread Factor in Mbed OS

Tags: mbed, lora

I'm trying to set the Spread Factor to 12 in Mbed, but there's no specific interface for that in the [header](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/features/lorawan/LoRaWANInterface.h). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921947/11108302) suggested to set the Data Rate to 0 but it doesn't actually seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is not working on this? As long as you (as the answer in the other question stated) set this either in ABP mode or after the Connection was established in OTAA mode this works fine. Note that the data rate is dependent on the channel plan that you load in. DR0 in EU868 means something different than DR0 in US915. The list of data rates and its corresponding spreading factor and bandwidth can be found in the [regional parameters document](https://lora-alliance.org/sites/default/files/2018-04/lorawantm_regional_parameters_v1.1rb_-_final.pdf).

**EU868**

[image: Data rates EU868]

**US915**

[image]